# Simulating a web browser C#

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, .net-core, headless-browser

I'm trying to extract data with `HtmlAgilityPack` from various websites by downloading their HTML code with `client.DownloadStringAsync()`. This has been working flawlessy so far, but I recently encountered a problem with one of the websites I tried to download this way. Instead of the actual content of the site which can be seen in a browser, it just said "Loading...". After checking networking in chrome, it seems that the GET request just gets a raw HTML, which doesn't actually include any of the data I need and instead it is mostly initialized by Javascript. I found the Selenium WebDriver which should do what I want it to, however I think it will conflict if I try to run all of that on a Raspberry Pi (which is what I'm designing this project for). If there are any alternatives, let me know or if it works on unix based systems too. Here is the Http Getter I used so far:

```cs
private async Task<string> HttpGet(string URL) {
  using var client = new HttpClient();
  using var request = new HttpRequestMessage {RequestUri = new Uri(URL), Method = HttpMethod.Get};
  using var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
  if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound) return "404";
  return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

After attempting to use the aformentioned NuGet package with Chrome, I managed to get heaps of different errors which were all foreign to me. Here's my code:

```cs
private string SeleniumGet(string URL) {
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.AddArgument("headless");
  options.BinaryLocation = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\chromedriver.exe"; //Probably not gonna work on an RPi
  using ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
  return driver.PageSource; //Unsure if this is source code, doesn't really matter for now - program crashes when initiating chrome driver
}
```

Currently am stuck on it saying `Invalid --log-level value.`, but I had other ones like `unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist.` however, I can't reproduce that one. Currently only the invalid log level error pops up, which crashes when constructing the `ChromeDriver`. Thanks for the help in advance. If the site I try to access matters, [This is it](https://5e.tools/bestiary/lacedon-tftyp.html). Looking at the GET request in networking shows the blank page with loading on it.